# Spring Boot Startup Analysis Tool

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot

I am trying to use [this tool on github](https://github.com/lwaddicor/spring-startup-analysis) to analyze my spring boot app's startup time. Here's my main class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(lazyInit = true, value = {"com.test.app","com.github.lwaddicor.springstartupanalysis"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ApiApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My application starts up fine but when I try to navigate to: `http://localhost:8080/spring-startup/` I get the following message:

```
{"status":401,"message":"Authentication failed","errorCode":10,"timestamp":1519416149986}
```

I tried editing the security filters like so:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers(,
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/configuration/security",,
                "/spring-startup",
                "/webjars/**");
    }
}
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by commenting out the overriden `configure` method. Not optimal but I only need to run this locally once so not a big deal to turn security off either.

Answer (score 0):

I think `antMatchers()` alone is not sufficient since you just tell the system which resources are affected but you do not specify how to deal with them. Append `.permitAll()` and it should work.

I am using something like this:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD, "/**").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/ui", ...)
            .permitAll()
.antMatchers(basePath + "/**").authenticated()
...
```

basePath is the path to the rest api which should be secured.